# Python: What's the role of doublequote and escapechar in csv module?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

The documentation states that:

```
doublequote: Boolean flag that determines how the quote character
(quotechar) is handled when it appears in a field. If True, the
character is simply doubled. If False, an escape character
(escapechar) is used as a prefix. The default is True.

escapechar: Character used as an escape character when the delimiter
appears in a field and quoting is QUOTE_NONE. The default
value is None.
```

Can some provide an easy example on how these two arguments works?